# Minimizing the number of parent rows for a distinct column in a child table

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have three tables with the following format

```
A        B       C
-----    -----   -----
aKey     bKey    fk_c_b
         fk_b_a  c_enum
                 c_value
```

`aKey` and `bKey` are the primary key for each table, `C` does not have a primary key. `fk_b_a` and `C.fk_c_b` are the foreign keys that points to the parent table. `c_enum` is a enum of 87 different values. `C.c_value` is float that can be any value

The relationships between the tables are:

- (`A.aKey`) 0..1 --- * (`B.fk_b_a`)
- (`B.bKey`) 0..1 --- * (`C.fk_c_b`)

There are:

- 57,668 rows in A
- 650,768 rows in B
- 34,734 rows in C

I need to display a distinct list of all `c_enum` values and their parents, however If two rows in `C` share the same `fk_c_b` and `c_value` values but different `c_enum` values I can use not those two rows in the distinct list.

```
select aKey, bKey, c_enum, c_value, newid() as id 
into #myResultSet
from A
inner join B on fk_b_a = aKey
inner join C as temp1 on fk_c_b = bKey
where c_value not in (select c_value from C as temp2 
                         where temp1.c_enum <> temp2.c_enum 
                            and temp1.fk_c_b = temp2.fk_c_b 
                            and temp1.c_value = temp2.c_value)

--This is the step that I do not know how to optimize
delete #myResultSet where id <> (select top 1 id from #myResultSet as t1 where #myResultSet.c_enum = t1.c_enum)
```

Also in that process I need to minimize the the distinct count of aKey and bKey. So If I did

```
select count(distinct aKey), count(distinct bKey), count(*) from #myResultSet
```

the result would have the minimum values possible. The optimal result is `1, 1, 87` and the worst case would be `87, 87, 87`. My current method does not attempt to get minimal values (my results are `14, 17, 87` which is not bad, but I think that is just luck with this dataset, running on a different dataset may return worse results) and I am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do it the right way.

What would be the correct way to solve this problem? My current method is not optimal all and I have been having a lot of trouble figuring out what I need to do to build `#myResultSet` with minimal values for `count(distinct aKey)` and `count(distinct bKey)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution. On the delete step I put the these two order by clauses in

```
delete #myResultSet where id <> 
    (
    select top 1 id 
    from #myResultSet t1 
    where #myResultSet.c_enum = t1.c_enum
    order by count(aKey) over(partition by aKey), 
             count(bKey) over(partition by aKey, bKey)
    )
```

This gives me `10,13,87` which I think is the optimal solution I can get with my data set.

If I am wrong or there is a better way to do this I am welcome to more answers.